# Sound an amplifier makes when you plug / unplug a cable

Tags: waves, acoustics, electronics, signal-processing

When you plug, unplug or even touch a jack cable of an aplifying system with speakers, one can hear a low-pitch sound that is of roughly always the same frequency, which does not seem to depend on the device (Hi Fi chain, guitar amplifier...)

- How is this sound produced ?
- Is there a particular reason the frequency of the signal is always the same ?

Comment: Is it the grid frequency hum at 50 hertz  or 60 hertz (depending on where one is)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What makes the buzzing sound when touching an audio line?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/63807/)

Comment: Hi Dimitri. I hink this is really an electronics question not physics, and indeed [exactly the same question has been asked on the electronics stack exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/63807).

Comment: I was not sure and it indeeds answers my question. Thanks, feel free to close, I don't know about the duplicate policy between different stack sites. I have a feeling it is still of interest for physicists

Answer (score 3):

Your body acts as an antenna and depending on your location your surrounding is covered by 50,60 Hz EM waves. That could be what you are hearing. There are also other signals but eiher they are too weak or out of hearing spectrum. You can also confirm this by touching an oscilloscope probe.

Comment: That seems to be in the correct frequency range. Thanks, people on the electronics stack also mention the body capacity (~ 100pF) that could make the system body + line oscillate